# Scraping data from within multiple div classes into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some data off a dashboard and am stuck with trying to get some data within multiple `div classes` into a pandas data frame. How should I go about trying convert something like this :

```
[<div class="map-item" data-companyname="Apical Group" data-country="INDONESIA" data-district="Jakarta Utara" data-latitude="-6.099396000" data-longitude="106.951478000" data-millname="AAJ Marunda" data-province="Jakarta" data-report="http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/AAJ_Marunda.pdf" id="map_item_4645">AAJ Marunda</div>,
 <div class="map-item" data-companyname="Apical Group" data-country="INDONESIA" data-district="Lubuk Gaung" data-latitude="1.754005000" data-longitude="101.363532000" data-millname="Sari Dumai Sejati" data-province="Riau" data-report="http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/Sari_Dumai_Sejati.pdf" id="map_item_4646">Sari Dumai Sejati</div>,
 <div class="map-item" data-companyname="Kutai Refinery Nusantara " data-country="INDONESIA" data-district="Balikpapan" data-latitude="-1.179099000" data-longitude="116.788274000" data-millname="Kutai Refinery Nusantara " data-province="Penajam Paser Utara" data-report="http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/Kutai_Refinery_Nusantara_.pdf" id="map_item_4647">Kutai Refinery Nusantara </div>]
```

Into a data frame like this:

```
no  companyname country district    latitude    longitude   millname    province    report
1   Apical Group    INDONESIA   Jakarta Utara   -6.099396   106.951478  AAJ Marunda Jakarta http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/AAJ_Marunda.pdf
2   Apical Group    INDONESIA   Lubuk Gaung 1.754005    101.363532  Sari Dumai Sejati   Riau    http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/Kutai_Refinery_Nusantara_.pdf
3   Kutai Refinery Nusantara    INDONESIA   Balikpapan  -1.179099   116.788274  Kutai Refinery Nusantara    Penajam Paser Utara http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-daemeter.com/files/Kutai_Refinery_Nusantara_.pdf
```

So far, this is code I have put together to get the multiple div classes from the web page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Link of Neste dashboard
url = 'http://nestetraceabilitydashboard.com/nestes-pfad-traceability-dashboard' 
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

divList = soup.findAll('div', attrs={ "class" : "map-item"})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can access the tag's attributes with the `.attrs` attribute. So we can create a dictionary with all the tag attributes (except class and id) and pass it to a dataframe.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://nestetraceabilitydashboard.com/nestes-pfad-traceability-dashboard' 
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

divList = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class" : "map-item"})
data = {}
for div in divList:
    for k,v in div.attrs.items(): 
        if k not in ('class', 'id'):
            k = k.split('-')[1]
            data[k] = data.get(k, []) + [v]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head(3))
```

The dataframe:

```
                 companyname    country       district      latitude  \
0               Apical Group  INDONESIA  Jakarta Utara  -6.099396000
1               Apical Group  INDONESIA    Lubuk Gaung   1.754005000
2  Kutai Refinery Nusantara   INDONESIA     Balikpapan  -1.179099000

       longitude                   millname             province  \
0  106.951478000                AAJ Marunda              Jakarta
1  101.363532000          Sari Dumai Sejati                 Riau
2  116.788274000  Kutai Refinery Nusantara   Penajam Paser Utara

                                              report
0  http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-dae...
1  http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-dae...
2  http://naturalhealthytreat.com/sites/neste-dae...
```

---

***An advice on `requests`***

It's best to use `.text` instead of `.content`, because it holds the decoded response content (text). So always use `.text`, unless the response a is binary file (image, pdf, etc).

***About `BeautifulSoup`***

`findAll` is used for backwards compatibility with `bs3`, in `bs4` it's renamed to `find_all`. Also, you can use attributes as [keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments), for example:

```
find_all('div', class_="map-item")
```

Here I used `class_` for the class attribute because `class` is a Python keyword, but for other attributes (id, href, etc) you can use their name as it is.

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam, these are really helpful tips for me!

Comment: Your every answer provides me with something new to learn. I would never look for that variable in response. I have been able to use `BeautifulSoup` to get that. I may have one last question on this tomorrow and then I'll create any question describing any issue I might have in future. It is always a pleasure to be in contact with you. Thanks.